# Please, make Ironman synonym of iron-man

Tags: feature-request, tags, tag-synonyms

I just used Ironman tag on mobile site and the site refused to accept it because there was a similar tag. Better create Ironman tag and link it to iron-man.

Comment: why not just use the correct and pre-existing tag?

Comment: To be fair,  the app does not help you by suggesting the alternative. In fact no tags can be made in the app AFAIK

Comment: @AncientSwordRage i just tested both the ios app and the mobile site. typing "iron" in the tag field in both brings up suggestions

Comment: @phantom42 maybe I should start using the app again?

Answer (score 6):

No, because the site already does this for you.

[image: error when trying to create ironman tag]